# type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, mysql

```
'DinnorApp.DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context
```

I have a problem with that kind of error, my code is here

```
   public int addUsuario(string nombreCompleto, string usuario, string correo, string contraseña, string palabraClave, byte[] imagen)
    {
        users = new Usuario();
        DinnorAppWeb2.Usuario usuario3 = new DinnorAppWeb2.Usuario();
        soap = new DinnorAppWeb2.WebService1SoapClient();
        usuario3 = soap.addUsuarioConImagenDesktop(DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest(nombreCompleto, usuario, correo, contraseña, palabraClave, imagen));
        users.nombreCompleto = usuario3.nombreCompleto;
        users.usuario = usuario3.usuario;

        if (users.nombreCompleto != null && users.usuario != null)
        {

            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The code above, is in winform, that information i use webservice

On the references file is

```
  // CODEGEN: Parameter 'imagen' requires additional schema information that cannot be captured using the parameter mode. The specific attribute is 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/addUsuarioConImagen", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    DinnorApp.DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenResponse addUsuarioConImagen(DinnorApp.DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/addUsuarioConImagen", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DinnorApp.DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenResponse> addUsuarioConImagenAsync(DinnorApp.DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenRequest request);
```

The code above, is when i call a service reference(webservice)

```
 [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/addUsuario", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    int addUsuario(string nombreCompleto, string usuario, string correo, string contraseña, string palabraClave);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/addUsuario", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> addUsuarioAsync(string nombreCompleto, string usuario, string correo, string contraseña, string palabraClave);
```

The code above, i can invoke a method with parameter easily, but the error 
i think the problem is the byte[] but i don't know why, because if i change byte[] to string or int or similar in parameter, that would be normal like rest.

The byte[] is for save or add image on mysql. So how can i solve it? 
I hope someone can help.

Sorry for my english.

You would realize it that somewords is in spanish.

**EDIT:**

I solved it , this is the correct code:

```
DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest add2 = new DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest(nombreCompleto,usuario,correo,contraseña,palabraClave,imagen);
 soap.addUsuarioConImagenDesktop(add2);
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing a `new` before `DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest`

Comment: I did that, DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest ad = new DinnorAppWeb2.addUsuarioConImagenDesktopRequest();, but i can only can variable, i mean, like ad.nombre  . i want to invoke the method